# Extract words from [" "] in R

Tags: r

I have a table called "Words":

| numbers | Words |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ["a", "b", "c"] |
| 2 | ["c", "d", "e", "f"] |

Now, I want to put all words together in a vector, like vector is a, b, c, c, d, e, f. Then, I could use `unique()` to get unique words, the result is a, b, c, d, e, f.
How could I do this in r?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Words` is a data frame, this will get you what you want. First make the data easily available using `dput()`:

```
Words <- structure(list(numbers = c(1, 2), Words = c("[\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"]", 
"[\"c\", \"d\", \"e\", \"f\"]")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

Chars <- gsub("\"", "", gsub("\\[|\\]", "", Words$Words))
Chars
# [1] "a, b, c"    "c, d, e, f"
strsplit(Chars, ", ")
# [[1]]
# [1] "a" "b" "c"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "c" "d" "e" "f"
unique(unlist(strsplit(Chars, ", ")))
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"
```